# Why is my GPO not being applied on Terminal Servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have a GPO linked to the Users OU, with some User Configuration settings set (specifically, settings for Folder Redirection). These work fine when users log on to their desktops, but they do not apply on the TS. There are no errors in the event log relating to Group Policy. Running gpresult /r on the TS indicates that the policy is not being applied. Why? One suggestion I've seen is to link the GPO to the TS OU, but why would that even be necessary? The TS is running Server 2008 SP2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the ou where the remote desktop server is located has a gpo with loopback policy processing, with 'replace'.

Comment: Nnnn......... [checks GPMC.msc] yep. You're right.